# "Scale out" socket.io with node.js worker threads

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-worker-threads

I've been "scaling out" a single-threaded socket.io app by using the [cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) long before node.js added [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/worker_threads.html).

But as having multiple processes involves (in my case) heavy usage of IPC, copying the same high-bandwidth data to all workers results in significant overhead. So instead -
**is it possible for socket.io to make use of worker threads?** The goal is to use more than just one core.

I can think of two different ways that this may be possible:

- having multiple, completely separate socket.io instances, each running on its own worker thread (e.g. each servicing a different tcp port - that's how my current [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) solution works)
- having a single socket.io instance use multiple threads internally (in which case it would perhaps have to be doing something like epoll - so I kind of doubt socket.io has that built-in)

N.B. As worker threads are supposed to be used for *performing CPU-intensive JavaScript operations*, it remains to be seen how much can be gained by switching from multiple processes to multiple threads. But in general, I would not expect in-process to be slower than inter-process communication. Also, in the case of worker threads, data can be shared (rather than copied).